# Converting Java Optional to Scala Option in Interfaces

Tags: java, scala, interface

I am working with a Java interface that is implemented in Scala. The Java interface returns an optional:

```
public interface MyJavaInterface {
    Optional<Kitten> fetchKittenIfAny(String name));
}
```

Which is implemented by Scala with a return type wrapped in Option:

```
class MyScalaClass() extends MyJavaInterface {
  def fetchKittenIfAny(name: String): Option[Kitten] = {}
}
```

But I keep getting `incompatible type in overriding` error.

I've tried using OptionConverters within my Java interface code converting toJava and toScala but neither seem to work. What is the proper way to do the conversion within the Java interface?

Edit as a follow up question: Is there any way I can have a Java interface and scala implementation, and also communicate that the result of the method can be of Optional/Option type?

Comment: You can not convert magically in the interface, you have to manually make the conversion in the implementation

Comment: It wouldn't make sense that the interface knows about its implementations and adapt to them. Interface defines a contract. Implementations have to honour it.

Comment: When you overriding/implementing JVM only allow you to: relax requirements on arguments (take a supertype of original parameter type) or strengthen requirements on output (return a subtype of originally returned type). `java.util.Optional` and `scala.Option` are from completely distinct hierarchies, no amount of upcasting/downcasting will convert one into the other, so you can never use one in place of another when implementing interfaces. In Scala 3 you could sometimes use (as input) `Option[A] | Optional[A]` (union types) but Java (or older Scala) would not understand this notation.

Comment: You need to declare your output as `java.util.Optional[Kitten]`, `import scala.jdk.OptionConverters._` and then run `.toJava` on the `Option[Kitten]` value you computed before returning it from method.